# A specific aspx page hangs on postback forever

Tags: asp.net

In my application, out of 500 or so pages, only one specific page hangs forever. It keeps loading forever, never stops (I waited for 30 minutes).

Problem is this happens only in one or two off cases. Normally the same page works fine. It is a data entry page, so basically user will enter some data and we save the same in 2-3 different tables using a transaction. If I enter the data five times, it is possible it will hang 1 time, randomly. I tried saving exact same data five times, and it hung only twice, so clearly data is not at fault.

I also checked the database tables, and nothing seems to be locked either.

I am not sure, exactly why it is happening. I know it is extremely weird request, but I just want few suggestions for debugging.

Comment: How did you check the database tables? Did you use the SQL Profiler (assuming you use Microsoft SQL Server - other DBs definitely have something similar) to see wether the issue resides inside the database or your application? You could also run a profiler on the application and try to replicate the issue to see what method your application spends so much time in.

Comment: Apart from the obvious fact, that this problem is way too broad: have you actually stepped into your code and determinded the excact position in your stack, where it "hangs" ?

Comment: It hangs on the `ExecuteNonQuery` line. So, clearly because of database. On the other hand, I wrote a simple `select *` query in SSMS, and that works fine during this freeze. So, I am unsure whether it is the table that gets locked or something else.

And I know it is a broad question. I want just a starting point to figure out possible situations that cause this problem.

Comment: Can you add some code? Probably it's a transaction problem

Comment: It was a transaction problem, but not with insert. Select query was taking too long, locking up the table. I don't understand why it didn't timeout instead of running forever. Still for the time being, I added an index to make sure query doesn't take as long as it was.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I finally got it. It was really a stupid problem. I had three insert and one select query in the transaction. Insert queries were fine. Select query was the one causing the timeout locking the transaction. Added an index on the table that was used by select query, and now it works perfect.